# base64Binary datatype is equivalent to base64?

Tags: xml, types, semantic-web

"The base64Binary datatype represents Base64-encoded arbitrary binary data. In other words, the data is encoded by using the Base64 Content-Tranfer-Encoding defined in Section..." from XML Schema Essentials

So, what I understand is if we decode the value, we obtain binary data. Is it true? Can we also have something like base64String, base64float?
It is totally different if we have base64 and baseBinary?

Maybe, it is obvious but this confuses me when in the second line they say "the data is encoded by using the Base64 Content-Tranfer-Encoding " and they didn't specify "binary data".

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base64Binary is used to encode a sequence of bytes for transfer over a textual medium. The content is considered only as bytes.

In answer to your question, there is no need for base64String, base64Float etc because they are well defined formats.

base64Binary can be used to transfer either a String or a float if you transform that construct to a byte sequence and encode with base64. Decoding and transform in the opposite direction on the receiving side.